# having been participled?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, gerunds, past-participles, perfect-aspect, present-participles

Is anything wrong in this sentence?

> The enemy, beaten at every point, fled from the field.

According to my book it should instead be:

> The enemy, **having been** beaten at every point, fled from the field.

Why?

There is only one subject in this sentence, so there **should** only be one verb; that is, *fled*.

How can we use *having been* + the past participle?

What’s the difference between the two sentence structures?

Comment: Why do you think a subject can have only one corresponding verb?

Comment: The past participle _beaten_ is here used like an adjective to describe the condition of the enemy.

Comment: The words "beaten at every point" form a subordinate clause. The sentence would stand grammatically without them - the main verb being "fled". Using the verb composite "having been beaten..." would be perfectly alright - but it is almost entirely synonymous with "beaten...".

Comment: It's a reduced form, according to one analysis, after be-deletion ('having been' is omitted). Or if you consider the expanded form to exist but to be 'The enemy, who had been beaten at every point, fled from the field,' after whiz-deletion. Both covered before, though the passive forms are harder to locate.

Comment: Any book that tells you something a native speaker says is wrong is wrong. There is almost **never** only one correct way to say something (outside the artificial rules of a classroom). More likely there are fifty.

Comment: Be-deletion (here 'having been') is unremarkable. 'The ammunition used up, the opposing sides charged each other with bayonets' [[South American Travels_Henry Stephens](https://archive.org/stream/southamericantr00stepgoog/southamericantr00stepgoog_djvu.txt)]

Comment: What is the book?

Answer (score 1):

principal/main clause- The enemy fled from the field.

subordinate/dependent clause- who had been beaten. (passive)

The enemy, **who had been beaten** at every point, fled from the field

We can leave out 'who had been'.

The enemy, **beaten** at every point, fled from the field.

We can use perfect participle.

The enemy, **having been beaten** at every point, fled from the field.

Comment: Mohammad, please select your required text and hit `Ctrl+B` if you need to embolden it, or use the markdown option (B) provided in the text editor. For more details, see this [Help](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: This seems to at least reflect what I've already said in a comment. I didn't give an 'answer' as I couldn't find supporting references showing these equivalences.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence "The enemy, beaten at every point, fled from the field", ...beaten at every point...is similar to "....having been beaten at every point..."

It is the passive form of 'having + 3rd form',

like "Having completed the work, he proceeded on leave", changing into "The work having been completed (by him), he proceeded on leave."

Comment: Please cite a source in support.

Comment: @Kris: Please refer to this link: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98099/perfect-participle

Comment: You better include that reference, if appropriate, in the body of the answer, to make it a proper answer. Good Luck.